# Read column of text data and do the conditional statment in python

Tags: python, if-statement, text

This is my text data i want to read the "APR"th column in python and do the 
conditional statements. in my case If the value of APR is higher than 30 print from

```
15:46:06 PROJECT STARTED NOW
15:46:06 JAN  FEB MARCH  APR   MAY JUNE JULY AUG SEP OCT NOV
15:46:06 A— 1 00  22.1  22.1  0    3   0    0    0   0   23
15:46:06 B— 2 01  21.2  21.2  0    0   0    0    0   0   12
15:46:06 C— 3 02  20.1  20.1  0    0   0    0    0   0   26
15:46:06 D— 4 03  19.8  19.8  0    0   0    0    0   0   25
15:46:06 E— 5 04  20.9  30.0  0    0   0    0    0   0   15
15:46:06 F— 6 05  19.8  19.8  0    0   0    0    0   0   23
15:46:06 G— 7 06  21.6  21.6  0    0   0    0    0   0   16
15:46:06 H— 8 07  20.9  20.9  0    0   0    0    0   0   34
15:46:06 I— 9 08  20.9  20.9  0    0   0    0    0   0   27
15:46:06 END OF DISPLAY
15:46:06 ENDS
```

**my output should print if the "APR" column value is higher than 30 like below**

```
15:46:06 JAN  FEB MARCH  APR   MAY JUNE JULY AUG SEP OCT NOV
15:46:06 E— 5 04  20.9  30.0  0    0   0    0    0   0   15
15:46:06 F— 6 05  19.8  19.8  0    0   0    0    0   0   23
15:46:06 G— 7 06  21.6  21.6  0    0   0    0    0   0   16
15:46:06 H— 8 07  20.9  20.9  0    0   0    0    0   0   34
15:46:06 I— 9 08  20.9  20.9  0    0   0    0    0   0   27
15:46:06 END OF DISPLAY
```

Comment: Do you have a question to go  along with that story?

Comment: Hi Timgeb.just check with the Dth columns values and higher then 30 then print upto END OF DISPLAY line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you open the file, and save the content between `PFAF` and  `END OF DISPLAY` into a [pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) (just in case you need to do other operations on your data.

Then, you iterate over this DataFrame, when the row of column `D` is `> 30` you save the index, and exit the `for` loop using a `break`

Last step is to use [`array slicing`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to display all your DataFrame starting at the index you saved before.

```
import pandas as pd

CREATE_TAB_MODE = 0
DF_INDEX = None
df_columns = None
df_list = []

with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
      if line.startswith('PFAF'):
        CREATE_TAB_MODE = 1
      elif line.startswith('END OF DISPLAY'):
        break
      elif CREATE_TAB_MODE:
        if df_columns is None:
          df_columns = line.strip().split()
        else:
          df_list.append(line.strip().split())


df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=df_columns)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if int(row['D']) > 30:
    DF_INDEX = index
    break

print(df[DF_INDEX:])
```

Comment: I do have another query on your code can you please help me?

Comment: I probably can! If it is not a minor change, please post another question with the code you already produce and what struggle to do. If your question is well enough tested and written, I'm sure better coders than me can answer in a more appropriate manner!